# Base64 encoding/decoding on Android

Tags: c#, java, android, base64

I'm trying to access a .NET WebService, but I have a problem with the authorization header. I have a username and password for authorization, but my password is a little long so I can't send it. When I try half of it as a password I am able to send it. My first question is, how can I send this password to the server?

```
String auth = "1234567890:123430A6F987AEED954215FFA84254FAD92ACD54"; 
String encodedAuth = org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode(auth.getBytes());
//byte[] encodedAuth = android.util.Base64.encode( auth.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
String authHeader = "Basic " + encodedAuth ;
headerPropertyList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", authHeader));
```

Another approach I tried is to send as a byte array by using:

```
byte[] encodedAuth = android.util.Base64.encode( auth.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

But the `byte` is signed in Java and unsigned in C# so different values are created. I also can't find a solution for this situation. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem, I have used Apache Common Codec instead of using Android's own base64 encoding. [Apache Common Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi)

Comment: (+1) Could you also add code example how to base64 encode using Apache Common Codec; just to make answer better.